# What does it mean for vectors to be symmetrical?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetry

Say we have three $n$-dimensional vectors $A$, $B$ and $C$. Now let's say that $A$ and $B$ are symmetrical about $C$. In two dimensions, this seems to have a fairly obvious meaning, but for higher $n$, I'm not sure. What does this notion of symmetry mean in general?

Comment: In my opinion, symmetry with respect to a line (since you are essentially saying that $A$ and $B$ are symmetric with respect to the straight line generated by $C$) is not really relevant in higher dimension.

Comment: I for one am not totally sure what you mean even in two dimensions. Do you mean that A matches B after you reflect the plane along C?

Comment: Consider $\vec D=\vec A-\vec B$.  It is easy to show $\vec D \perp \vec C$.  I expect $\vec C$ and $\vec D$ would span a 2-dimensional subspace of the $n$-dimensional space that contains $\vec A$, $\vec B$ and $\vec C$.  If you started with just $\vec A$ and $\vec C$, the idea of symmetry might allow you to generate $\vec B$ by reflecting $\vec A$ about $\vec C$.

Comment: Any thoughts, SWatson, about the comments and answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson - I'm not sure. I'm going to reread that section of the article I was reading, and think about it. Thanks for your idea, it sounds very plausible.

Comment: How is that reading going?

Answer (score 1):

I would say it means $A$ and $B$ have the same length, that all three lie in the same 2-dimensional subspace, and the line through the origin and $C$ is the perpendicular bisector of the line segment joining $A$ and $B$.